# Webpack Loader - How can I know which module required a particular module?

Tags: webpack

I'm writing webpack loader. Can I know which source import/requir the loaded file/module?
Is there other webpack feature that can tell me which module required a particular module?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this in JS - what are you trying to achieve? Webpack is usually used to transpile/compile multiple js source files into  a single file. The dependencies you define are only used to ensure that webpack compiles a module's dependencies before it compiles the module itself, thus preventing dependency errors when executing the code in NodeJS or a user's browser.